# word frequency in multiple documents

Tags: python

i have a dataframe with the columns title and tokenized words.
Now I read in all tokenized words into a list called vcabulary looking like this:

[['hello', 'my', 'friend'], ['jim', 'is', 'cool'], ['peter', 'is', 'nice']]

now I want to go through this list of lists and count every word for every list.

```
wordfreq = []
for w in vocabulary:
    wordfreq.append(vocabulary.count(w))
```

This does not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your 2D list, into a normal list, then use `collections.Counter()` to return a dictionary of each words occurrence count.

```
from collections import Counter
bigLst = [['hello', 'my', 'friend'], ['jim', 'is', 'cool'], ['peter', 'is', 'nice']]
print(Counter([word for lst in bigLst for word in lst]))
```

output

```
Counter({'is': 2, 'hello': 1, 'my': 1, 'friend': 1, 'jim': 1, 'cool': 1, 'peter': 1, 'nice': 1})
```

Comment: Hi BuddyBob,
thanks for your answer! It is neccessary to match every count of words to its document but I don't get how to do that. Maybe you can help.

Comment: to it's document? I wouldn't be able to help because I have no idea what the question is. Maybe you can ask another question here after some time. But for now, if this has answered your question, consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark below the up/down vote buttons. And if you appreciated my time you can consider upvoting the answer too. Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

I think @BuddyBob's solution is adequate. In your code, the count() function will return the number of occurrences or something in a list. Since every index of the vocabulary list is a list, it will always record 1 as the frequency. So, you will have to loop to every element of each nested list and use a dictionary, or collections.Counter().